# Getting API response using cURL in PHP and storing the response in a MySQL Database. Cycling through the array and inserting/updating the database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently working on a project where I have to import some statistics into an MySQL Database. I'm able to retrieve a JSON String using the cURL function of PHP. After receiving the API response I convert it using:

```
$decoded_json = json_decode($api_response)
```

I now have an array that looks like the following (to make it easier I cut the array midway through)

```
array (
'status' => 'ok',
'meta' => 
array (
  'count' => 1,
),
'data' => 
array (
502268596 => 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'random' => 
    array (
      'damage_dealt' => 1443,
      'wins' => 4,
      'frags' => 5,
      'spotted' => 3,
      'battles' => 8,
    ),
    'tank_id' => 8257,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'random' => 
    array (
      'damage_dealt' => 155992,
      'wins' => 60,
      'frags' => 90,
      'spotted' => 85,
      'battles' => 99,
    ),
    'tank_id' => 3921,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'random' => 
    array (
      'damage_dealt' => 48407,
      'wins' => 27,
      'frags' => 58,
      'spotted' => 44,
      'battles' => 53,
    ),
    'tank_id' => 3713,
  ),
```

From that array I need to write the field "damage_dealt","wins","frags","spotted","battles" and "tank_id" into my database. I've already set up a connection to my database using mysqli.

Additional to that I need to store the "502268596" in the database  which is the "account_id".

The problem I'm having now is: How do I cycle through that array and get the fields into my database while they update if "account_id" and "tank_id" are already in the database? Right now I've set "account_id" and "tank_id" as Primary Keys for the database.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: in case you need the API response for whatever reason:

[Link](https://developers.wargaming.net/reference/all/wot/tanks/stats/?application_id=95f97675107994aa1aa0956246152c13&account_id=502268596&extra=random&fields=tank_id%2Crandom.battles%2Crandom.damage_dealt%2Crandom.frags%2Crandom.spotted%2Crandom.wins&in_garage=1&r_realm=eu&run=1#)

I've found a way to access the fields in the meantime.

```
//Getting tank_id
$tank_id = $decoded_json[data][$account_id][0][tank_id]
//getting the rest
$damage_dealt = $decoded_json[data][$account_id][0][random][damage_dealt]
//etc.
```

So my question now is: How do I cycle through the "0" part of the array and how do I update the values in my database if they already exist? Do I have to query my database for tank_id and account_id and then make a second query (insert/update) based on tank_id and account_id already being in my database?

working code to access all fields:

```
for ($i = 0; i< count($decode[data][$_SESSION['account_id']][$i]); $i++){
    $tank_id = $decode[data][$_SESSION['account_id']][$i][tank_id];
    $damage_dealt = $decode[data][$_SESSION['account_id']][$i][random][damage_dealt];
//etc.
}
```

EDIT: Working Code-Sample:

```
for ($i = 0; i< count($decode[data][$_SESSION['account_id']][$i]); $i++){
    $tank_id = $decode[data][$_SESSION['account_id']][$i][tank_id];
    $damage_dealt = $decode[data][$_SESSION['account_id']][$i][random]    [damage_dealt];
    $wins = $decode[data][$_SESSION['account_id']][$i][random][wins];
    $frags = $decode[data][$_SESSION['account_id']][$i][random][frags];
    $spotted = $decode[data][$_SESSION['account_id']][$i][random][spotted];
    $battles = $decode[data][$_SESSION['account_id']][$i][random][battles];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usertanks (account_id, tank_id, damage_dealt, frags, spotted, wins, battles) VALUES     ('$account_id','$tank_id','$damage_dealt','$frags','$spotted','$wins','$battles')    
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    damage_dealt='$damage_dealt', frags='$frags', spotted = '$spotted',      wins='$wins', battles = '$battles'";
    mysqli_query($db,$sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. User foreach to loop through the array

foreach($array as $key=>$value){

```
  //Write mysql insert query here, and access data from $value variable.
```

}

2. use following query syntax to insert/ update the records

   INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=3;

Good Luck.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I solved it in the meantime using trial & error ;)